# Pass array of objects as hidden field value into mvc controller

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc

I am using VS2015, MVC5.
My submit form:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input name="celo" type="hidden" value="994" />
        <input name="pispis" type="hidden" value="Došel je prošel pisani Vuzem!" />
        <input name="userji" type="hidden" 
            value="[{'ID':1,'Name':'John','TotalPayed':0,'TotalDebt':0},
                {'ID':2,'Name':'George','TotalPayed':0,'TotalDebt':0},
                {'ID':3,'Name':'Simon','TotalPayed':0,'TotalDebt':0},
                {'ID':4,'Name':'Antonio','TotalPayed':0,'TotalDebt':0}]" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit test"/>
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public void Test(int celo, string pispis, List<User> userji)
    {

    }
```

Class User:

```
    public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TotalPayed { get; set; }
    public int TotalDebt { get; set; }         
}
```

Values 'celo' and 'pispis' are transferred correctly. I have a problem with array of objects 'userji' - it is null on controller. Is there a way to pass array of objects into controller using submit form?

Comment: You cannot. You need to create an input for each item in your collection (using a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `User`. But what is the point of sending an whole lot of data to the client and then sending it all back again unchanged. Just get the data again in the POST method if you need it.

Comment: Array of objects is dynamically created on the client. I want to pass that array to the server.

Comment: How is it generated? In order to POST to that method you need `<input name=[0].ID ... />`, `<input name=[1].ID ... />` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke - that way I can save one object, creating four hidden fields, just like you've described. How can I save array of objects?

Comment: You can save as many objects as you like - the `[#]` is the indexer in the collection - it just needs to start at zero and be consecutive. The codein my last comment will bind 2 the `ID` property of 2 `User` objects

Comment: Basically if I have ten objects with four properties each, there will be 40 hidden fields generated? I mean, I need to create 40 hidden fields?

Comment: Yes, 1 input for each property of each item in the collection. But I suspect there is something wrong with your design it you think you need to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@FrenkyB You could change the binding to be a string and then digest it into a list like this.

```
public void Test(int celo, string pispis, string userji)
{
    var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(userji);

    //stuff
}
```

Comment: Or as people commented you can create inputs for each with loops, etc. This is a way to take your current json input and turn it into to a list quickly.

Answer (score 7):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var users = new List<User> 
    {
        new User { Name = "John", TotalPayed = 0, TotalDebt = 0 },
        new User { Name = "George", TotalPayed = 0, TotalDebt = 0 },
        new User { Name = "Simon", TotalPayed = 0, TotalDebt = 0 },
        new User { Name = "Antonio", TotalPayed = 0, TotalDebt = 0 }
    };

    <input name="celo" type="hidden" value="994" />
    <input name="pispis" type="hidden" value="Došel je prošel pisani Vuzem!" />

    @for(int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
    {
        var user = users[i];

        <input name="userji[@i].Name" type="hidden" value="@user.Name" />
        <input name="userji[@i].TotalPayed" type="hidden" value="@user.TotalPlayed" />
        <input name="userji[@i].TotalDebt" type="hidden" value="@user.TotalDebt" />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit test"/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of doing what you're asking is kind of a cheat.  The way I have done it in the past is to pass as a string and then parse the data as JSON on the controller side.

Comment: It works... string comes to controller. It would be ideal if that string is somehow transferred to List<User>... otherwise, good point. I mean, that it  comes to controller already as List<User>.